# How to convert Hex data to Byte in Delphi7

Tags: delphi, hex, byte, delphi-7

I have a problem that is how to convert Hex file to byte in Delphi 7. I have Hex data: $0183, and I want to convert it to byte, but when I convert it to byte the data was change become 131. I want the data keep it 0183 because i want to and this value with another Hex data $0001. I have write the source code as below:

```
procedure TForm1.dxBarButton9Click(Sender: TObject);
var
h: array [1..12]of string;
EA2: String;
EA1: word;
begin
h[1]:='01';
h[2]:='83';
EA2:='$'+copy(h[1],1,2)+copy(h[2],1,2);    
Edit1.Text:=(EA2);
EA1:= StrtoInt(EA2);
EA1:= EA1 and $0001;
Edit2.Text:=IntToStr(EA1);
end;
```

My problem is, the data h[1]&h[2] actually the data that I received from serial communication which is hex file. I just wrote it the code in here as that, just to make it simple. And after I got h[1] &h[2], I need to combine this data becomes EA1=0183. Then I want to do "and " operation with $0001(integer). How I can do that?
I appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Declare `EA1` as `word`,`Cardinal` or `Integer`.`Byte` is too small for values larger than 255.

Comment: Hi Lu RD, Yes I have declare it as word, and now I have complete get 0183. But because right now 0183 is not hex file any more, so I need to add $ in front of 0183 becomes $0183. Then I can do "and" operation with $0001. Do you have any idea how to add $ in front of 0183?

Comment: This is utterly confused.

Comment: Nobody can help you if you can't explain the problem clearly. Don't ask in comments. Edit the question and ask it clearly. What's wrong with writing $0183?

Comment: Hi David, I have edit my question, please take a look.

Comment: You are aware that the result of operation: $0183 AND $0001 is $0001?

Comment: yes, I am aware about it, the result is $0001, thats what I want, I have update my question, please help me to solve that. Thank you

Comment: The code you presented in the update is working as described. What is your question?

Comment: Hi Lu RD,  What I want is change the data type of '$0183' (which is string) becomes $183(integer), so that on next step I could do $183 and $0001. That's my purpose. Thanks a lot

Comment: Your code does exactly that.

Comment: This is a total waste of time

Comment: To add "$" in front of 183, type "i,h" (without quotes) in the evaluator (Ctrl+F7) or Watches (Ctrl+Alt+W), in Delphi IDE, not just "i". By default, Delphi shows values in decimal form, you have to add ",h" after a value to see it in the hexadecimal form.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot store $0183 in a single byte, because this value requires Word or two bytes
2. It seems you confuse byte **value** with its **representation** for human eyes - in decimal, hex, binary or another form. For example, your `EA1` byte is low byte of needed value and it is `83hex=131dec`

To look at value in hex, use Format with `%x` specifier

**Edit**

You have a byte containing value 65 (as example). It might be shown as decimal 65, as hex $41, as binary 01000001, as Ansi char 'A'. But it is still the same set of ones and zeros.

When you transform string value '$0183' to Word (note again: Byte is not enough), you'll get word value 387 decimal, **it is the same that hex $0183**. And you can make binary AND operation with Word var.

Comment: Actually I just want the hex value on h[1] & h[2] which has data type string, could become $0183( which has data type integer) so that I could do "and" with $0001 (which $0001 is has integer data type). Do you have any Idea?

Comment: My answer is still valid. This is your third question in this theme and there is no progress in task understanding. You definitely should learn basics of programming before real problem solving.

Comment: Hi Mbo, first, yes i just do programming using delphi in couple months so need to learn more, and as your suggestion to use %x, as I know in delphi I can use format('%x',[387]), then I will get 0183 in hex, but still it will in string format & I still cannot do "and" operation. Because "and" operation need to do in integer.

Comment: Please reread my second paragraph. Note that my example with ByteBuf is more suitable for data treatment.

Comment: Hi Mbo, Maybe I am too stupid to understand what you try to explain. I am so sorry about it.

Answer (score 0):

## How to view values in hexadecimal form in Delphi IDE

To view the value in the hexadecimal form in the Delphi IDE, add ",h" (without quotes) after the variable name in the evaluator (Ctrl+F7) or Watches (Ctrl+Alt+W). By default, Delphi shows values in decimal form, you have to add ",h" after a value to see it in the hexadecimal form.

## How to convert string values from hexadecimal form to integer in runtime

Don't make an array of strings, just accumulate all the hexadecimal digits in a single string, and then convert the whole string to an integer value. Just use the following function, ValHex.

```
var
  s: String;
  i: Cardinal;
begin
  s := '183';
  if ValHex(s, i) then // pass pure hexadecimal characters only, without a '$' prefix.
  begin
    // now i has value of $0183
  end;
end;
```

Here is the code of the ValHex. It accepts pure hexadecimal characters only, without a '$' prefix.

```
function ValHex(const s: string; var AOut: Cardinal): Boolean;
var
  a, i, L, start: Cardinal;
  c: Char;
begin
  Result := False;
  AOut := 0;
  L := Length(s);
  start := 0;
  if (L = 0) then Exit;
  while (start < L-1) and (s[start+1] = '0') do Inc(start); // skipping leading zeros
  if (L-start > 8) then Exit; // checking for overflow
  a := 0;
  for i := 1+start to L do
  begin
    C := s[i];
    a := a shl 4;
    case C of
      '0'..'9' : Inc(a, Ord(C) - Ord('0'));
      'A'..'F' : Inc(a, Ord(C) - Ord('A') + 10);
      'a'..'f' : Inc(a, Ord(C) - Ord('a') + 10);
      else Exit;
    end;
  end;
  AOut := a;
  Result := True;
end;
```

You can also use Delphi standard function StrToInt(), see the documentation on how to use it - you should add '$' prefix for hexadecimal values, otherwise it will treat an argument as a decimal value.

## How to convert integer values to a hexadecimal string in runtime

```
function Hex8(A: Cardinal): string;
const
  HexCharArr: array [0..15] of Char = '0123456789ABCDEF';
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 8);
  for I := 0 to 7 do
  begin
    Result[8 - I] := HexCharArrW[(A and $F)];
    A := A shr 4;
  end;
end;
```

You can also use Delphi function Format() to convert an integer to a hexadecimal string, see the documentation.

Comment: This is what [SysUtils.TryStrToInt](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToInt) or `StrToInt` does: *TryStrToInt supports strings in the following hexadecimal notations:
Delphi: $1234 and 0x1234.* So `StrToInt('$0183')` gives the value 387 in decimal notation.

Comment: Hi Maxim, I have try your code but when I run it gives value "i' becomes 387. It just the same as StrToInt($0183). What I want is the '$0183' (string) becomes $183(integer), so that on next step I could do $183 and $0001. That's my purpose. Thanks a lot

Comment: When using the evaluator to view the value of "i", dont type "i", type "i,h" (without quotes), so you will see $183, not 387. Regardless of how you see the value of the variable, you are able to logical operations with i, like AND, OR, XOR, etc.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  EA1: word;
begin
  EA1 := StrToInt('$0183') and $0001; // $0183 and $0001
  // or
  EA1 := StrToInt('$'+IntToHex(0183, 4)) and $0001; // 183 and $0001
  Caption := IntToStr(EA1);
  Caption := '$'+IntToHex(EA1,4);
end;
```

Comment: Hi Ercument,  right now I have store it not in single byte, I already convert it to byte perfectly becomes 0183, but I still have a problem how to do "and" operation with $0001? because right now 0183 is not hex file any more, so I need to add $ in front of 0183 becomes $0183. Then I can "and" with $0001. Do you have any idea?

Comment: So, if you need add $ front of 0183, why not add $ to front of 0183 :)